# I cant reduce the height of input with following css code

Tags: html, css

Please see this css code

```
#ContactForm .wrapper {
min-height:30px;
padding-bottom:8px;
} 
#ContactForm .bg {
border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
background-color:#e9e9e9;
float:left;
}
#ContactForm .input {
width:200px;
height:12px;
background:none;
padding:6px 10px 6px 10px;
color:#000;
font:10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

When I test it in browser (firefox) the input block is of some height.. I try reducing the top and bottom padding value from 6 to zero but no avail.
Also reducing height from 12 to lower value does not help.

It is stubborn and fixed to some height. What could be wrong??
I can provide with other data also, if needed.

This is html code

```
<div  class="wrapper"> <strong>Phone:</strong>
        <div class="bg">
                <input type="text" class="input" >
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: And *only* in Firefox..?

Comment: @Anthony.. what is jsfiddle?

Comment: JS Fiddle is, well: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It allows you to post live demos of your HTML, CSS, JavaScript problems in order that we can see a minimal ([Short, Self-contained (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/)) demo of your problem on a site that allows for us to edit your code to correct/test solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think reducing the height from wrapper will halp.. if not the height must be controlled from some other factor.. check that..

on a look on your code this is the solution..

update us for the same..

```
#ContactForm .wrapper {
min-height:30px;   (CHECK THIS)
padding-bottom:8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the form your input is in is has the id "ContactForm"
2. Remove the space between `#ContactForm` and `.input` like the following example

   ```
   #ContactForm.input {
   width:200px;
   height:12px;
   background:none;
   padding:6px 10px 6px 10px;
   color:#000;
   font:10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   ```

That should work.

Comment: #ContactForm {
 margin-top:-4px;
 line-height:26px;
    }

Woah here was the key.. 

this line height was fixing it to go below this 26 pixels... 
GOD save me from HTML.

Thanks guys for answering. I got is solved.. 

I think other might learn also from this.. :)